# how to show an array list in a JList in Java?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, drag-and-drop, jlist

I have an arraylist and want to show it on Jlist using gui, I am using drag and drop to make the form, so I need to fill the list dynamically.
I tried to get into the properties of the Jlist and make the model is a custom code but the problem which happened that the array list takes its elements from a text file, that means when I want to fill the array list I should call a method one of its parameters is a name of file.
When using this method try and catch shohld be used but when I set the model of the Jlist it minds use it! 
What should I do to make my array list shown on the form as a list?

```
    public static ArrayList<Beverage> readBeverageTextFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    ArrayList<Beverage> bevList = new ArrayList<>();
    Reader reader = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line;
    while (true) {

        line = buf.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }

        try {
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "|");

            String name = tokenizer.nextToken();
            //System.out.println("The name is " + name);
            String desc = tokenizer.nextToken();
            //System.out.println("The dest " + desc);
            double price = Double.parseDouble(tokenizer.nextToken());
            //System.out.println("The Price is " + price);
            double quantity = Double.parseDouble(tokenizer.nextToken());
            //System.out.println("The Quantity is " + quantity);

            double ex = Double.parseDouble(tokenizer.nextToken());
            double pac = Double.parseDouble(tokenizer.nextToken());
            double capacity = Double.parseDouble(tokenizer.nextToken());
            //System.out.println("The Capacity is  " + capacity);
            bevList.add(new Beverage(capacity, name, desc, quantity, price, ex, pac));

        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Beverage.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "error");
        }
    }
    return bevList;
}
```

Comment: What code do you have now?

Comment: This: `"When using this method try and catch shohld be used but when I set the model of the Jlist it minds use it!"` is not clear. Please clarify exactly what problems you may be having with your code, and please show your code (as @laune also requests).

Comment: I posted the method to fill the arrarylist , and this array list I want to show it as any components in Gui , it doesn't mater but I don't know how

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have a form called deleteProducts and want to show the array list in it, when I make the model of Jlist as a custom code it will be changed in the generated code by java and write this    jList1.setModel(Beverage.readBeverageTextFile("Beverage.txt").toArray()
and no way to make try and catch for the exception of file not found.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only using the ArrayList to read data into and then display it in a JList, then don't use an ArrayList. Instead use a [DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html), fill it with your file's data by calling `addElement(...)` on it, and then set the JList's model via `setModel(...)` with your data-filled model.

If on the other hand you absolutely **must** use an ArrayList to hold your data, then I see you having two possible options here:

- Use your ArrayList, but also create a DefaultListModel, and fill the list model with the ArrayList data using a for loop. The down-side, your data will be held in two collections, and there's no guarantee that the data will remain fully synchronized.
- Create an AbstractListModel using your ArrayList as a data nucleus. This would be the cleaner way to do this, but will require more effort on your part, including making sure that you call the proper `fireXXX(...)` notification methods for instance.

For more details, please see the [How to use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) tutorial.

---

**Edit** 
Regarding your code, @again, in place of an ArrayList, use a DefaultListModel. Key also will be how your objects display in the JList, and to get this right, you'll need to either give the Beverage class a decent `toString()` method, or else (and better) you should give the JList a decent ListCellRenderer.

Comment: GI will do another operations on the arraylist , delete and sort..etc.can I do this in DefaultListModel? @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: @user3159060: delete, use, sort, not by itself. For that you may want to create an AbstractListModel with your ArrayList as its data nucleus. You can sort that ArrayList then.